# In VBA: Can I use a find function to define a variable that is then used to define a range?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dimensions

I am writing a code to do some simple excel data manipulation. Basically a column called "End User" has blanks in it and if that cell is blank I want it to pull the name from the parent "External Business Unit"

I wrote the code to do this but the issue is the data I receive changes over time so end user might be in column c one month and column d in another.

My current code is this:

```
Sub FindColumn()
'Set ws = Sheets("group")  'sheet with data
Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'ws.Select
'Dim xyz As Range
Dim rngaddress As Range

Set rngaddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("End User", , , xlWhole)
If rngaddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "End User column was not found."
   Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(rngaddress, rngaddress).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveCell.Value = "Final End User"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
'Set xyz = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Final End User").Offset(1, 0)'
 'Range("xyz" & Lastrow) = "=IF(d2="""",b2,d2)"
Range("C2") = "=IF(d2="""",b2,d2)": Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).FillDown
```

I successfully used the fine function with a variable to target a specific cell but I am struggling to use it to select a range that goes to the last row. I am not sure if it is because this required two variables or if I just have the syntax wrong. I am t
I attempted to use xyz in place of the C2 data but it would not work (commented out). Is there any way to do this so I do not have to use the the cell address and instead can use the find function, store that info in a variable, and define the range that way?

Example Data set would be

two columns one called external business unit one called end user. External business unit always have a name end user is randomly blank. Creating a column called final end user where blanks are filled with corresponding external business unit values.

Comment: `xyz` is the `Range` in question. You would not use `Range("xyz")`, but just `xyz`.

Comment: I might be over thinking it then. My question now I guess is how would I combine variable xyz and last row to select all the data in the end user column down to the last row.

Comment: `xyz.Resize(lastRow)` should work since your header is in row 1.

Comment: From the code we may conclude that `External Business Unit` is always in column `B`. You are inserting `Final End User` before (to the left of) `End User`. What do you plan to be left with in the end? Both columns where `Final End User` contains formulas, or is there something more to it? Correct me if the two assumptions are wrong.

Comment: I did not want to add confusion but actually External Business Unit could also change. Ideally if I solve this I could apply the same solution to the last row function always using "external business unit" but yes that is exactly what is happening. In a separate module I copy specific columns (also using the find function) to a dashboard. The whole point of this is to get rid of the blanks in end user, previously people were copy and pasting each blank item individually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Insert Column and Fill In Blanks

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub findColumn()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("group")  'sheet with data
    
    Dim eb As Range
    Set eb = ws.Rows(1).Find("External Business Unit", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If eb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "External Business Unit column was not found."
    Else
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, eb.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim eu As Range
        Set eu = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="End User", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If eu Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "End User column was not found."
        Else
            eu.EntireColumn.Insert
            ' Get the column strings only now, because 'euCol'
            ' has surely shifted, but 'ebCol' might have also.
            Dim ebCol As String
            ebCol = Split(eb.Address, "$")(1)
            Dim euCol As String
            euCol = Split(eu.Address, "$")(1)
            eu.Offset(, -1).Value = "Final End User"
            eu.Offset(1, -1).Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula _
                = "=IF(" & euCol & "2=""""," & ebCol & "2," & euCol & "2)"
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, not only does this work perfectly, It helped me better understand the String vs Range uses.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You BigBen. Using the resize command worked:

```
Set xyz = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Final End User").Offset(1, 0)
xyz.Resize(Lastrow) = "=IF(d2="""",b2,d2)"
```

Once they pointed out it was an issue with how I was using the variable I also got the code to work using this method.

```
Range(xyz, xyz) = "=IF(d2="""",b2,d2)"
Range(xyz, xyz).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), Cells(Lastrow, ActiveCell.Column))
```

Now I will try and use variables for the if function as well.